# How can I create my own PHP system template?

Tags: php, templates

I hope to create a  PHP system template for my own scripts. How can I do that with PHP, HTML, CSS and JS?

I don't want to use any ready smarty template.

Comment: are you talking about a template engine or a template that you can put your code inside?

Comment: What's a "ready smarty" template? Do you just mean anything that already exists?

Answer (score 0):

## Do not reinvent the wheel again

Use production ready library like twig or just smarty. If you are interested in modern architecture dive into a source code of these libraries.

Comment: Who or what are you quoting? What doors?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ....

I found this on youtube ..

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJFBB8ZNMWI

Comment: Off-site links are [not useful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).